# Как выполнить один скрипт JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как выполнить один скрипт JS для всех div отдельно?

```js
$(".salle").each(function() {
  document.getElementById('plus').onclick = function(event) {
    var span = document.getElementById('amount').innerText;
    var a = document.getElementById('amount').innerText;
    span = Number(span);
    var b = 1;
    var count = Number(span) + b;
    document.getElementById("amount").textContent = count;
  };

  document.getElementById('min').onclick = function() {
    /*var span = document.getElementById('amount').innerText;*/
    var a = document.getElementById('amount').innerText;
    var b = 1;
    var count = a - b;
    document.getElementById("amount").textContent = count;
    console.log(count);
  };

});
```

```html
<div class="salle">
  <butt id="plus">+</butt>
  <span id="amount">0</span>
  <butt id="min">-</butt>
</div>

<div class="salle">
  <butt id="plus">+</butt>
  <span id="amount">0</span>
  <butt id="min">-</butt>
</div>
```

Comment: пожалуйста добавь верстку и код который у тебя есть.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".class_name").each(function(){
    //ваш код
    //в $(this) содержится текущий элемент
});
```

Comment: Добавил код html и js

Answer (score 1):

У вас проблемы с кодом- не должно быть на странице двух разных элементов с одинаковым `id`.

Переделал это на классы:

```js
$(".plus").click(function(){
    var $amount = $(this).closest('.salle').find('.amount');
    $amount.text(+$amount.text() + 1);
});

$(".min").click(function(){
    var $amount = $(this).closest('.salle').find('.amount');
    $amount.text(+$amount.text() - 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="salle">
  <button class="plus">+</button>
  <span class="amount">0</span>
  <button class="min">-</button>
</div>

<div class="salle">
  <button class="plus">+</button>
  <span class="amount">0</span>
  <button class="min">-</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Без кода трудно сказать, но попытаюсь догадаться о чем идет речь.
И если я правильно понял, то тебе надо:

```
// Задать всем div'ам одинаковый класс;
var divs =$('.className');
for( var i = 0 ; i < divs.length ; i++ ){ 
   // тут код что нужно делать с div'ом
}
```

Comment: Добавил код html и js